# Is there any transport in thrift 0.11.0 c# library that support Asynchronous operations?

Tags: c#, thrift

I have use thrift (version 0.11.0) c# compiler  to generate c# library that support async operation. The command line as below:

```
thrift-0.11.0.exe --gen csharp:async Message.thrift
```

When I start a client, the program throw an `Thrift.Transport.TTransportException` exception with message:

> Asynchronous operations are not supported by this transport

The client code snippet:

```
TTransport transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
MessageService.Client client = new MessageService.Client(protocol);
client.Add(someObject);
```

Since `TSocket` does not support asynchronous operations, I checked all classes defined in `Thrift.Transport` namespace. Seems none of them support async operation.
[image]

I found a `TNonblockingTransport` class in Java, which seems support async operation. **Is there any equivalent thrift transport for .Net/C#** ?

**Update**

I've checked [Apache Thrift Language Support](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/Languages). And it does not support nonblocking server in C# yet. It does support it in .net core 2.x which is not applicable for my scenario since I'm working with WPF.

[image]

Comment: I am facing same problem while trying thrift in Unity3D game engine, as client. Blocking implementation works fine. But Async ones not. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @flankechen no, I finally use block api.

Comment: thanks, ifso, did you try async task things in csharp for a block api call?

Comment: yes, that's my current workaround

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `netcore` generator even if your entire application isn't .Net Core (which doesn't support WPF).

Use the `netcore` generator to create a .Net Standard library you should be able to reference.  We use this approach in three different WPF applications.

The `Thrift.Transports.Client` namespace contains clients with `async` member functions.